# Link to the issue number on GitHub within a commit message

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Is it somehow possible to **automatically** have a link to GitHub issue number in the `git commit` message?

Comment: Related: [Cross-referencing commits in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376475/cross-referencing-commits-in-github)

Answer (score 1283, accepted):

**Just include `#xxx` in your commit message to reference an issue without closing it.**

With new [GitHub issues 2.0](https://github.blog/2011-04-09-issues-2-0-the-next-generation/) you can use these synonyms to [reference an issue and close](https://github.blog/2013-01-22-closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) it (in your commit message):

- `fix #xxx`
- `fixes #xxx`
- `fixed #xxx`
- `close #xxx`
- `closes #xxx`
- `closed #xxx`
- `resolve #xxx`
- `resolves #xxx`
- `resolved #xxx`

You can also substitute `#xxx` with `gh-xxx`.

Referencing and [closing issues across repos](https://github.blog/2013-03-18-closing-issues-across-repositories/) also works:

```
fixes user/repo#xxx
```

Check out [the documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords) available in their Help section.

Comment: `Fix issue #xxx` doesn't work for me, any ideas? It references the issue, but doesn't close it.

Comment: @Dennis remove the word "issue"

Comment: @JamesTomasino that's possible - I've noticed that this hasn't been working for me when I'm working on a branch called `dev`.

Comment: @JonathanCairns  **EDIT**: Check out the below answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12830089/1253944             **ORIGINAL**:The convention for an issue on dev branch would be to either use the url (I believe it gets shortened) or use user/repo/branch/issue/7 or /repo/branch/pull/7. Don't quote me on that. It's something like that though. [Github Blog on Issues 2.0](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation)

Comment: i'm not going to be the person who moves this answer from 666 votes to 667, but this was VERY helpful.

Comment: Worked for me.  The only thing I can say about this is when I see xxx, I assume it is a 3 digit number, but obviously `fixes #9` for instance will work.  It would be nice if the answer makes this explicitly clear that it is for any length number and you do not need to pad with zeros.

Comment: The # character will mess up with Vim as it is used for comments, beware! If you do a rebase any text after # may disappear.

Comment: I think, when a merge request is related to the issue, it doesn't close it automatically on Gitlab, which is cool.

Comment: For anyone in doubt, as of 2021 Aug 3, `gh-xxx` still works.

Comment: Interesting that for Azure DevOps, typing hash in the commit message brings up the actual list of issues (work items), whereas for github it doesn't. Can something be done in this regard?

Comment: One tip, if using #xxx - don't put them at the beginning of your commit message otherwise you will have an interesting conundrum when you need to do a commit --amend  .  Git refuses the amend because your commit message looks like a commented line and therefore does not exist.

Comment: I'm getting `This issue will close once commit ee7ae7e is merged into the 'main' branch.`, and I pushed to the main branch but it's not closing? The commit message was `Add bad word filtering (fix #2)`

Comment: `fixes user/repo#xxx` does not work (anymore?) in GitHub Desktop.

Comment: Worth saying that these keywords are case insensitive (`Close #xxx` works just like `close #xxx`)

Comment: Actually you don't need a prefix for `#xxx`, because GitHub tracks all `#xxx` in text files (for example, `changelog.txt`) in a repo. Even more, if you try to close from a commit comment, then you have to reopen it later if a fix actually does not fix or fixes partially. Better to go to the issue manually, retest it and then close it.

Comment: Another method is to put the issue full url link: `https://github.com/USER/REPO/issues/NUMBER`

Comment: Beware of repository rewrite issue: `A repository rewrite involves reappend all backtrack links to rewrited commits with issue links` : https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/49227

Answer (score 197):

If you want to link to a GitHub issue *and* close the issue, you can provide the following lines in your Git commit message:

```
Closes #1.
Closes GH-1.
Closes gh-1.
```

(Any of the three will work.) Note that this will link to the issue and also *close* it. You can find out more in this [blog post](https://github.blog/2009-04-15-github-issue-tracker/) (start watching the embedded video at about 1:40).

I'm not sure if a similar syntax will simply link to an issue without closing it.

Comment: You can just use the number of the issue (for example #456) it will link to the task without closing it.

Comment: I would choose "gh-1" over "#1" simply because you never know if the repository gets exported/mirrored to somewhere other than github.  Then, the "#1" won't make much sense.

Comment: @mipadi: is the `.` after "Closes GH-1` necessary? Also, is it case-sensitive?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I don't believe the period is necessary. Not sure about case-sensitivity.

Comment: `message (closes GH-28)` works for me, not sure if everything is case-insensitive.

Comment: `I'm not sure if a similar syntax will simply link to an issue without closing it.` #1 without one of the fixes/closes variations before it will refer to an issue without closing.

Answer (score 86):

github adds a reference to the commit if it contains #issuenbr (discovered this by chance).

Comment: just tested it, works like a charm, thanks... this is the one that should be marked as correct answer...

Comment: this should be part of the accepted answer. sometimes you just want to mention the issue and are not doing anything to it yet.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I'd also recommend that it's helpful to prefix it with something, like "Related to #..." or "Similar to #..." to help give some context. i.e. If it doesn't fix it, it may be similar to or a side effect of it, etc.

Answer (score 80):

You can also cross reference repos:

```
githubuser/repository#xxx
```

xxx being the issue number

Answer (score 24):

they have an nice write up about the new issues 2.0 on their blog
https://github.blog/2011-04-09-issues-2-0-the-next-generation/

synonyms include

- fixes #xxx
- fixed #xxx
- fix #xxx
- closes #xxx
- close #xxx
- closed #xxx

using any of the keywords in a commit message will make your commit either mentioned or close an issue.

Comment: That was already in my list, I do not think they are case sensitive.

Answer (score 18):

In order to link the issue number to your commit message, you should add:
`#issue_number` in your git commit message.

**Example Commit Message from** [Udacity Git Commit Message Style Guide](https://udacity.github.io/git-styleguide/)

```
feat: Summarize changes in around 50 characters or less

More detailed explanatory text, if necessary. Wrap it to about 72
characters or so. In some contexts, the first line is treated as the
subject of the commit and the rest of the text as the body. The
blank line separating the summary from the body is critical (unless
you omit the body entirely); various tools like `log`, `shortlog`
and `rebase` can get confused if you run the two together.

Explain the problem that this commit is solving. Focus on why you
are making this change as opposed to how (the code explains that).
Are there side effects or other unintuitive consequenses of this
change? Here's the place to explain them.

Further paragraphs come after blank lines.

 - Bullet points are okay, too

 - Typically a hyphen or asterisk is used for the bullet, preceded
   by a single space, with blank lines in between, but conventions
   vary here

If you use an issue tracker, put references to them at the bottom,
like this:

Resolves: #123
See also: #456, #789
```

You can also reference the repositories:

```
githubuser/repository#issue_number
```

Comment: It makes no sense (and actually annoys me) that they use "feat" as an abbreviation for "feature", especially when at the same time they use "refactor" which is even longer than "feature".

Comment: @MichelJung you could argue that `feat` is used more often than `refactor`, also there's no obvious abbreviation for `refactor` (`ref` could mean reference, `rf` is too unclear, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Just as addition to the other answers: If you don't even want to write the commit message with the issue number and happen to use **Eclipse** for development, then you can install the eGit and Mylyn plugins as well as the GitHub connector for Mylyn. Eclipse can then automatically track which issue you are working on and **automatically fill the commit message**, including the issue number as shown in all the other answers.

For more details about that setup see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/GitHub/UserGuide

Answer (score 5):

One of my first projects as a programmer was a gem called [stagecoach](https://github.com/omnikron/stagecoach) that (among other things) allowed the *automatic* adding of a github issue number to every commit message on a branch, which is a part of the question that hasn't really been answered.

Essentially when creating a branch you'd use a custom command (something like `stagecoach -b <branch_name> -g <issue_number>`), and the issue number would then be assigned to that branch in a yml file.  There was then a [commit hook](https://github.com/omnikron/stagecoach/blob/master/lib/githooks/commit-msg) that appended the issue number to the commit message automatically.

I wouldn't recommend it for production use as at the time I'd only been programming for a few months and I no longer maintain it, but it may be of interest to somebody.

Comment: I think your answer is trying to address the exact question from the OP, i.e. "a way to **automatically** have a link to the issue added in the commit". All other answers rely on programmer remembering to add "Fixes #..., Resolved #... etc." phrase to the commit and this is not going to happen each time as we know it. Upvoting.