# Closing multiple issues in Github with a commit message

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I know you can close issues by putting `closes #1` or `fixes #1` in the commit message. What is the best way to close multiple issues in the same commit message?

Also, it appears that using `fixes` rather than `closes` doesn't create a link from the commit message to the issue, but it *does* close the issue. What's up with that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262

Answer (score 228, accepted):

`Closes #1, closes #2, closes #3; rest of commit message.`

The `closes` clauses can be anywhere in the message and `fixes` is a valid synonym:

```
This fixes a memory leak in foo() that closes #4,
also fixes #5 which is a duplicate.
```

---

The following *used to* work, but nowadays only *references* issues #2 and #3.

`Closes #1, #2, #3`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, it only closes the first item in the list and not the others. Has the syntax changed since this post? I've Googled it, but there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of help out there about this.

Comment: Agreed. Fixes #1, #2 works to reference both... but only closes #1.

Comment: @waldo I think this worked when I wrote it -- nowadays then, how about `Closes #1, closes #2, closes #3`? Verbose and redundant, yes, but maybe it works?

Comment: Yup, "Fixes #1 - Fixes #2 - actual commit message." works and makes some sense (if verbose) - i.e. I clearly close and refer (without closing) multiple different issues from a single commit message.

Comment: You don't have to put the closes/fixes part of the message anywhere specific in the commit message.  For example, "refactored class foo, fixes #3, new feature bar, closes #8, don't break backwards compatibility" should close #3 and #8.  Still have this 'reference only' issue as of March 2012..

Comment: Any idea why they changed the behaviour of `Closes #1, #2, #3`? I find it ridiculous to write 10 `closes` plus the numbers of the issues that are to be close instead of a single close and all the numbers after that. :-/

Comment: Just a small side-note: I have issues doing that in **GitLab** but not in **GitHub** so it also depends on whether the API of the git-based VC platform supports it or not.

Comment: @Darthfelt That's a little off, because they have to be together. For example, `This closes issue #3` will only reference `#3`. It doesn't matter where `closes #3` or `fixes #3` etc is at in the commit message, but it has to be joint.

Comment: I just used "Fixes #1 and fixes #2", both issues did NOT close

Comment: I know it's overkill but they could use copilot to parse these messages and get the correct references. I know, it's extremely overkill, but still it would be as easy as telling a teammate to close those issues

Answer (score 51):

The answer and a comment to that answer mention the following format:

> Closes #1, closes #2, closes #3; Actual commit message

If I had a project worth participating in and someone sent a pull request with such commit messages, I would refuse the pull no matter how beautiful the code was.

It is possible this is just a matter of my personal preference and will end up beaten to the very ground by people used to compact commit messages that clutter up Git history summaries, but I would much rather see commit messages with the format:

> Summary of the change made.
>
> Fixed following bugs:
>   * Modified error loader, fixes #1
>   * Returned a nonstale pointer, fixes #2
>   * Applied new graphics to gui elements, closes #3

He asked for the *best* way to close multiple issues.

Also note that if you push the commit with the message to any other branch than the current default branch of your repository, the issues will only be referenced. Pushing the commit to the main branch will close the issues. See: [Link to GitHub issue number not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977161/link-to-github-issue-number-not-working)

Comment: Just tried your way. I've got to be honest, I really like this!

Answer (score 18):

Note that, since [January 2013](https://github.com/blog/1386-closing-issues-via-commit-messages), "Closing Issues via Commit Messages" has changed:

Now when you enter "`Fixes #33`" in a commit message, **issue 33 will only be closed once the commit is merged into your default branch (usually `master`)**.

> This is super useful because it means the issue's open / closed status will map to your default branch.
>   If the bug isn't fixed in your default branch, the issue will remain open.
>   Once the commit with the fix is merged into your default branch the issue will be automatically closed.
>
> You can use any of these keywords to close an issue via commit message:

```
close, closes, closed, fixes, fixed
```

As illustrated by the question "[Closing a GitHub Issue while on a different branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14154054/6309)", this causes some confusion at first.

Answer (score 9):

Here from Github self a documentation: [Linking a pull request to an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue#linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue-using-a-keyword)

```
Resolves #10, resolves #123, resolves octo-org/octo-repo#100
```

[image: Screenshot from GitHub Documentation]

Answer (score 6):

["Closing issues using keywords"](https://help.github.com/en/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords) is a document from GitHub that describes how to close issues, tags and how to close multiple issues.

To answer your questions the answer from GitHub is:

> [Closing multiple issues](https://help.github.com/en/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords#closing-multiple-issues)
>
> To close multiple issues, preface each issue
> reference with one of the above keywords. You must use the keyword
> before each issue you reference for the keyword to work.
>
> For example, This closes #34, closes #23, and closes
> example_user/example_repo#42 would close issues #34 and #23 in the
> same repository, and issue #42 in the "example_user/example_repo"
> repository.