# Automatically closing issue from pull request in GitHub

Tags: github, workflow, pull-request

How do I close an issue using a pull request on GitHub? I know about [closing multiple issues with a commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547445/closing-multiple-issues-in-github-with-a-commit-message), but it's a different case.

I would like to close the issues not from a commit, but from the description of the pull request. More like

Pull request:

```
Name: bla bla
Description ... , _fixes_ #123
```

And when merging the pull request, the `#123` to *automatically* close. Is this possible?

Comment: one can close an issue from the pull request on github when actually doing the `merge`, by adding a description message like `closes #123` or `fixes #242 #111` where `#number == issue number`

Comment: Have you tried this on a sample repo? Create two issues, have one reference the other with "closed #xxx" and close that one. What happens

Comment: The workflow is the following: you have an issue #111, and a pull request #112. When merging the pull request into a branch (by hitting Merge pull request button), github requires additional info in a textarea and asks you to "Confirm merge". In that textarea, one can add "closes #111" and when hitting Confirm merge, the issue #111 will get closed. Not the ideal way, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Then that should be the answer

Comment: This is unfortunately not even optional: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/66741

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As you [mention in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235620/automatically-closing-issue-from-pull-request-in-github/15827689#comment20031380_12235620),  the **merge from the pull request** will result in a commit.
It is on that commit message you can add a "`close #xx`" in order to trigger the closing of an issue.

However, as mentioned in "[Closing multiple issues in Github with a commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3547445/6309)", in GitHub blog post "[Closing Issues via Commit Messages](https://github.com/blog/1386-closing-issues-via-commit-messages)" (January 2013), and in the [current GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue#linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue-using-a-keyword).

> Now when you enter "`Fixes #33`" in a commit message, **issue 33 will only be closed once the commit is merged into your default branch (usually `master`)**.
>
> This is super useful because it means the issue's open / closed status will map to your default branch.
> If the bug isn't fixed in your default branch, the issue will remain open.
> Once the commit with the fix is merged into your default branch the issue will be automatically closed.
>
> When you do make a commit in a non-default branch with the "`Fixes #33`" syntax, the issue will be referenced with a tooltip:
>
> [image: Closing Issue]
>
> You can use any of these keywords to close an issue via commit message:
>
> ```
> close, closes, closed, fix, fixes, fixed, resolve, resolves, resolved
> ```

---

As [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16846288/6309) by [cosmolev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972676/cosmolev) (upvoted), the blog post from [May 14th 2013 "Closing Issues via Pull Requests"](https://github.com/blog/1506-closing-issues-via-pull-requests) adds pull requests as a way to close an issue:

> **some issues take more work than a single commit to close**.
> That's why **you can now close an issue from a Pull Request**.
> All you have to do is include the special keyword syntax (eg. "`fixes #5`") in the body of your Pull Request.
>
> [image: comment on pull request]
>
> the referenced issue will automatically be closed when the PR is merged into the default branch.
> It even works across repositories.

As [John Eikenberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127316/john-eikenberry) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235620/automatically-closing-issue-from-pull-request-in-github/15827689#comment100305974_15827689), the help page "[Closing issues using keywords](https://help.github.com/en/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords)" does mention:

> To close *multiple* issues, preface each issue reference with one of the above keywords.
> You must use the keyword before each issue you reference for the keyword to work.

For example, `This closes #34, closes #23, and closes example_user/example_repo#42` would close issues #34 and #23 in the same repository, and issue #42 in the "`example_user/example_repo`" repository.

Comment: nice, didn't know it was fixed. Last time I tried the fixes #33 in a commit, the issue would close. Cool.

Comment: @AndreiPetre as mentioned below by cosmolev, and as edited in my answer, pull requests can now close an issue as well.

Comment: Small addendum. To close multiple issues in one pull request, you need the keyword before each issue. Eg. `fixes #123, fixes #321, fixes #999`
ref: https://help.github.com/en/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords

Comment: @JohnEikenberry Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 17):

It's finally possible: https://github.com/blog/1506-closing-issues-via-pull-requests

Just add **resolve #18** to pull request message

where 18 is an issue number

Comment: Interesting. +1. I have included a reference to that blog post in my answer for more visibility.