# Link to GitHub issue number not working?

Tags: git, github

I used the reference to github issues with closes #xxx frequently. Since a few days it seems that this doesn't work anymore. The link from commit to issue still works, but I don't see the commit in the issues anymore. And they are not closed anymore.

Does somebody know if they changed something? I liked this feature very much so it would be nice if I can get working it again.

Thx for any suggestions

Comment: This sounds like something to ask GitHub support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who is interested in this,

I asked Github Support and its true they made some changes on this. Here is the answer from the support:

> Referencing an issue will now only close the issue if the commit is made to the default branch of the repository, which is usually 'master'. If you made the commit to a different branch, the issue will be closed when you merge that commit in to the default branch.