# Closing a GitHub Issue while on a different branch

Tags: github, branch, issue-tracking

I am *not* working on the *Master* branch. I am working on a different one *newFeature* , which is also published on github.

I know how to to close issues when working on the Master branch: `Closes #XXX`.

However this only works when I am working on the Master branch, if I switch over to the other branch or a different one and do a commit with `Closes #XXX` it does not close the issue.

My question is:
Is it possible to do this and how do you do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

i'm pretty sure github issues are agnostic of branches.

are you talking about a local branch or a tracking branch? if your not specifically tracking the branch on github, the branch will not be pushed - thus github will not see your `close #XXX` command. here's some info on remote branches from the progit book http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

### UPDATE

i emailed this problem to the github support staff and they confirmed this is expected behavior. here's the response i got from them:

> It is because of a recent change we made. Issues are only closed when the commits are merged to the default branch of your repository. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am tracking this branch on github. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: agreed. i just setup a gh repo, made an issue, made a branch, refrenced the issue from a commit, and pushed it. in the gh commit history it makes the reference to the issue, but that reference was not made in the issue itself. i would submit this problem to github.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just double checking to be sure. It could have been that it was possible but I was just not aware.

Comment: Do you know if this has changed? It would be great to be able to close issues from the `development` branch.

Comment: These days it looks like it acknowledges that you closed it via another branch (via a tooltip), but the issue remains open until that commit is in your default branch. I haven't seen a way to customize it; I'd prefer to be able to close the issue entirely from any branch.

Comment: While this answer is useful, it doesn’t answer the OP question and therefore shouldn’t be the accepted one… (strictly speaking)