# What are the smart commit commands supported by Jira in Github?

Tags: git, github, jira

I have just linked Jira with Github following [this](https://github.com/marketplace/jira-software-github) link.

1. How can I open and comment on the issues in one of my public github repositories?
2. Could I get a list of sample commit messages with currently supported issue tracking options in Github? (open, comment on an issue, multiple issues etc.). A web-link where it is listed would also suffice.

What did I try so far?

- Read [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-960155400.html) link. It requires some commands like *JIRA-123* etc in the commit message? Didn't help much.
- Closed an issue successfully using the commit message `closes #2` as suggested in [this stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547445/closing-multiple-issues-in-github-with-a-commit-message). It closed the issue `2`. This thread is from 2010. (One of the reasons for not replying in that thread and asking a new one).

Answer (score 1):

The supported commands are called as your transactions in your workflow. E.g. you have a state called "In Progress" -> transaction called "review" -> state 2 "In Review". Then your commit message should be

```
JIRA-123 #review
```

Furthermore make sure that the email address that is used to commit the change is also used by the jira account. Also that this email address is added as valid email address to the github user account.