# Github commit message tagging

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to assign tickets or add labels to github issues in a commit message?

Example:

```
@usera ready for you to sign off for #Testing
```

where @usera is a user and #Testing is a label ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well unfortunately it looks like it isn't possible without some hackery. I put together a simple sinatra app (that you can throw on heroku) to handle a few new handlers

[Github Postcommit Shinies](https://github.com/joshrendek/github-postcommit-shinies)

To assign to a user you can do:

```
git commit -a -m 'updates #23 assigned =USERNAME';
```

To add labels you can do:

```
git commit -a -m 'updates #23 ~QA ~testing'
```

You can also mix and match:

```
git commit -a -m 'updates #23 ~QA ~testing =QAUSER'
```

Comment: can you also remove labels ?

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen support for referencing text labels or users in commit messages.  However, you can reference an issue by its number in a commit message:

> ready for you to sign off for #341

If there is an Issue #341 in your GitHub project, GitHub will recognize that `#341` references an existing Issue, and will link to it.

For more info on referencing issues in commit messages:
https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation

An example of what I have described from the above link:

- [Mentioning an issue in a commit](https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/img/9bf399559491d3224bfe5c8d861042439f07a6b3/687474703a2f2f6769746875622d696d616765732e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f626c6f672f323031312f6973737565732d6e6578742f636f6d6d69742d6d656e74696f6e2d726573756c742e706e67)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the updated project link.**

https://github.com/joshrendek/github-postcommit-shinies

**Tutorial To Set This Up.**

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/adding-labels-and-re-assigning-github-issues-via-commit-message/

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to this (Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment if that would be more appropriate) but I just did a commit on github using `@username` and it created a linke in the commit message on github.com just fine.

You can see the commit message here if you're interested: https://github.com/kremerk/SqliteORM/commit/52008b80c71291e0164175f7b089ef3c096798a0