# Cross-referencing commits in github

Tags: git, github

I'd like to reference commits in other repos (in this case submodules) in the github issues of my main repo. Is it possible to do so without typing the full hyperlink in a way similar to how github creates a shortened hyperlink from the commit number?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/

Comment: See also [Link to the issue number on GitHub within a commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

The answer, so us lazy people can find it without following the link to the [Autolinked References and URLs section of the GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/#commit-shas):

```
User/Project@SHA
```

For example:

```
mojombo/god@be6a8cc1c1ecfe9489fb51e4869af15a13fc2cd2
```

Short SHAs work as well (as long as they are unique):

```
mojombo/god@be6a8cc
```

Comment: For those looking to reference _issues_ in other repos, it works as expected: `user/repo#45`.

Comment: And this is important: use the text of the reference as is. Do not wrap it into a markdown link, such as `[xxx](mojombo/god@be6a8cc)`

Comment: doesn't work for me with googlemaps/android-maps-utils@3cba85f04a79095160015f62a8438eb76adbbe6f

Comment: @J.D. : thanks so much, very helpful. Citation: https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/

Comment: To link to a commit in an organization use the format: `orgname/repo@SHA` such as `nodejs/node@90008f8`.

Comment: This seems not to work in GitHub Desktop