# Automatically prepending Github issue number to all commits

Tags: git, github

This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-github-issue-number-with-commit-message) but was not answered as far as I can see.

I am writing a script to automate git workflow.  When a topic branch is created it automatically creates a github issue referencing it - is there any way to automatically prepend this issue number to all commits made in that branch?  I am thinking there may be a way using git hooks but I'm unable to find it.

I am aware that manually adding #xxx to the beginning of each commit message will do this; what I am interested in (and what was never answered in the original question) is if there is a way for this to be added automatically.

Comment: http://henrik.nyh.se/2009/09/git-hook-to-auto-reference-tickets-from-the-branchname might be worth a read. It references tickets from the branch name though, but it might be a start.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great article that I hadn't seen before.  Looks like I should be able to fork it and bend it to my will!

Comment: @Frost I think your comment is worth being turned into a real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at how Henrik Nyh did a similar thing, by extracting issue numbers from branch names. You might be able to get something out of that.

Henrik's article is [here](http://henrik.nyh.se/2009/09/git-hook-to-auto-reference-tickets-from-the-branchname).

Comment: Thanks again for this, I was indeed able to get it working with my script.  Here's my fork if anybody is interested: https://gist.github.com/1632375