# Can't see linked commits in Github issues

Tags: github

We link our commits to related issues as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-github-issue-number-with-commit-message)

But today I can't see any commit link in issues? (Maybe Github don't support this feature any more or there is a bug)

How can I see commits related to issue in this situation?

Comment: is it public project, may you provide example? e.g. It used to work for me some time ago.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide repo info because it is private