# Github Commit Syntax to Link a Pull Request/ Issue

Tags: git, github, commit, github-flavored-markdown

I've seen commit messages that refer to a specific issue / pull request.  What is the syntax to include a specific repository's issue or pull request?

Comment: There is a great lib on github for creating these links programmatically: https://github.com/doowb/github-issue-template, and a website where you can drop in a few bits of info and it will generate the link: http://doowb.github.io/github-issue-template/

Comment: See also "[Multiple issue and pull request templates"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481402/6309)", since January 2018.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link to the issue number on GitHub within a commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message)

Comment: @DidierL Date-wise, shouldn't the linked question be a duplicate of mine?  I can understand closing this for the linked question when looking at upvotes and content (the `Fixes XXXX` syntax wasn't set up when initially asked), I'm more wondering what constitutes a question being a duplicate over an other. I've had similar old questions closed before, but calling this a duplicate isn't _exactly_ correct.

Comment: Well, the other question is older isn't it? (2009 vs 2014). As you noted it also has more votes, and AFAICT the questions are exactly the same, and the answers present here are covered in the accepted answer over there.

Comment: Oh, you are right!  I looked at the incorrect date (edited date vs. created date), whoops!

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use the **[documented](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/autolinked-references-and-urls)** auto-linking format for issues across repositories.

- **Syntax:** `{owner}/{repository}#{issue_number}`
- **Example:** `mojombo/jekyll#1`

When such formatted text is present in a commit message, it's automatically transformed into a clickable link which will redirect one to `https://github.com/{owner}/{repository}/issues/{issue_number}`

Comment: That does indeed work!  I tried looking through the documentation and couldn't find anything there, thanks for linking.  [Example commit with this format.](https://github.com/droppedonjapan/extensions.js/commit/6170afadd91684a1b8043ea0f5bc9d9322fcb54e)

Comment: The provided syntax works for linking across repositories (ie. a commit in repo B linking to an issue in repo A). When pointing at issues in the same repository, you can use the short syntax `#{issue_number}`

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for the clarification, it is definitely very useful.

Comment: This is good for issues, but I don't see anything about linking to a Pull Request.

Comment: @bryanbraun This syntax also works for Pull Requests.

Comment: @nulltoken Precisely what is the syntax for citing (and linking) to a pull request? If `mojombo/jekyll#1` is about issue 1, what is the syntax for pull request 1 ?

Comment: @RobStewart the same. You can't have both issue 1 and pull request 1 in a repo.

Comment: How do I know where this was done if it says "{user} added a commit that referenced this pull request" on PR?

Answer (score 40):

Github share PR/Issue number use the same sequence.

So, one #number either one PR or one Issue.

Just use #number is OK.

Comment: This answer deserves more attention.  I'd never noticed that.  Thank you!

Comment: I wish they spelled this out in github's documentation.  I'm sure it's there somewhere, but I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 36):

Use `#1234` in a comment to reference pull request 1234 from the current repo.

Answer (score 2):

For linking to another repository, if you just paste the link to the issue or pull request, say `https://github.com/{owner}/{repository}/issues/{issue_number}`, GitHub will render it as

```
[{owner}/{repository}#{issue_number}](https://github.com/{owner}/{repository}/issues/{issue_number})
```

For example, https://github.com/jlord/sheetsee.js/issues/26 will render as [jlord/sheetsee.js#26](https://github.com/jlord/sheetsee.js/issues/26).

See https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/#issues-and-pull-requests