# 'username' pushed a commit that referenced this pull request?

Tags: git, github

Today we could see a strange message on our Github pull requests.

`optiguy pushed a commit that referenced this pull request on 18 Apr`

No-one from the team has ever seen it before or know what it means.
We have a slight idea that it might something related to some rebasing gone wrong and there are duplicated commits in the branch.

Can anyone answer why we see this message and why there are zero useful results on google searching for that specific message?

https://www.google.dk/#q=%22pushed+a+commit+that+referenced+this+pull+request%22

Comment: It means that someone pushed a commit whose message included the text `account/repo#pushId`. It should include a link to that commit, so you can go and have a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github Commit Syntax to Link a Pull Request/ Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019608/github-commit-syntax-to-link-a-pull-request-issue)