# Force every commit on github project to be issue-only

Tags: git, github, commit, issue-tracking

My teacher requested me to make this to a github project: Each time the user wants to commit something, he needs to specify an issue that was created on github to associate the commit with the issue. If he commits something without associating any issue, the system should not let the commit be done. In other words: You can ONLY commit if you associate an issue with the commit.

Is it possible to do this with a java project with maven? And what about a web project with maven?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-github-issue-number-with-commit-message?rq=1

Comment: To require it on the `github` servers, I think you'd need to do that on github's servers.

Comment: You can use a `commit-msg` hook to check this locally before committing. Obviously that won't work for arbitrary commits coming in e.g. from pull requests.

Comment: is there a tutorial for commit-msg on git? I don´t even know where is the .git/hooks folder that this tutorial explains: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks.

Comment: @user3653781 Every git repository has a hidden `.git` directory at the root.

Comment: yeah, there´s a .git folder, but how can i use it to get what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Github does not allow you to create a `pre-receive` hook such that you can look at commits and ensure that they are linked to issues.

You can probably go the pull request route and merge only commits that have the proper format.

Comment: i don´t understand. Pull request route? Is there a tutorial anywhere i can follow?