# Git link to issues

Tags: git, github

I was reading that there is a way to close a issue in github with a commit but I am not ready to close it I just want to link to it, to show progress. How can I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link to GitHub issue number with commit message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-github-issue-number-with-commit-message)

Comment: @Thilo I was looking at that. I do not want to close it thought

Comment: They say over there, that you can just mention `#xxx` in the commit message (where xxx is the issue number) to get a link without closing the issue.

Comment: Yep that is it, that worked like a champ