# Github add label to an issue based on commit message

Tags: github, webhooks

Is it possible to add/toggle labels on issues based on a commit message ?

I know that writing "fix #xxx" will close the issue, but what if I'd like to apply a label to it instead ? "v3 #xxx" => label the issue #xxx with the already defined label "v3"

...or something simpler, but the idea is to be able to set a label without visiting the issue page.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message

Comment: Oh sorry ! I realize my vocabulary was totally wrong. I don't want to TAG but LABEL the issue with one of the custom labels defined in my repository.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think that's possible from a commit message. Would a CLI tool work? There's [hub](http://hub.github.com/). Or you could DIY using the github api.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message . This is about labels

Answer (score -2):

If you comment on the issue with *just* the issue number, github's markdown gnomes will automagically turn that into a link. Just precede the issue number with the pound sign AKA hash tag.

I.e.

```
my great commit message

[re #12]
```

will change the `#12` to a link when viewed on github.

Comment: That is true, but it's not what we're looking for here, we want LABELS