# Is it possible to reject a commit on Github if the commit isn't formatted correctly?

Tags: git, github, webhooks

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742691/1501285) answer, it is possible to reference an issue in a Github commit.

Is it possible to reject a commit of it is *not* formatted like this?

Example:
`fix gh-12 foo bar` is correct
`foo bar` would be wrong

**Update:**

Almost there, this still isn't working... Any thoughts?

I now have the following in: `.git/hooks/commit-msg`

```
#!/bin/bash
commit_regex='(gh-[0-9]+|merge)'

error_msg="Aborting commit. Your commit message is missing either a Github Issue ('gh-1111') or 'Merge'."

if ! grep -E "$commit_regex" <<< "$0"; then
    echo "$error_msg" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: $0 is your .git/hooks/commit-msg  .. you should be grepping the "$1" which is the first parameter to your commit-msg ..

Comment: also, that regex will pass any commit message which has the gh-[0-9] anywhere in the commit message .. For example "Oh my gh-0sh!" will pass the test :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python version could look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re
ret = 1
try:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as msg:
      res = re.match("^fix gh-[0-9]+.*$", msg.readline())
      if res != None: 
          ret = 0
except:
    pass
if (ret != 0):
    print("error_msg_goeth_here")
sys.exit(ret)
```

Typically its the first row that should match the pre-defined format but thats only my personal opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup [pre-receive hook](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/pre_receive_hooks/), but this feature is available only for GitHub Enterprise. If you are not using GitHub Enterprise you still can receive notification when commits are pushed using [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), but you cannot reject such push.

**Edit:**

Of course you can set local hook - see [rasjani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39768775/5508756).

Comment: pre-commit hook on on client would do the trick but then it requires that the hook script is provided *and* used ..

Comment: Aha, @rasjani, any insight in how to find some info about this?

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated the question. Any thoughts here?

Comment: actually, i should have said "commit-msg" hook, not pre-commit .. i'll add a reference as a answer ..