# Is there a short syntax to add a link to a file on the current repository within a commit message?

Tags: file, github, hyperlink, commit

GitHub has a [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message?rq=1) to add a link to a specific commit using its hash like [`bec0001`](http://example.com/) that can be used on a commit message. Is there a syntax to add a link to a file on the same repository? Something like:

> **Cool commit**
>
> Doing something useful. See also file [/package.json](https://github.com/atom/github/blob/master/package.json)

Couldn't find anything in the docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/autolinked-references-and-urls

Also tried [Relative link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#relative-links) with `../blob/master/`  and it didn't work on the commit message (only on the comments):
/package.json

Answer (score 0):

No, not using a file path.

The "[Autolinked references and URLs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/autolinked-references-and-urls)" mentions:

> References to URLs, issues, pull requests, and commits are automatically shortened and converted into links.

So you could reference the URL of a file, but:

- there is no short syntax
- It would be rendered as a full URL, as opposed to, for instance, a commit URL, like https://github.com/jlord/sheetsee.js/commit/a5c3785ed8d6a35868bc169f07e40e889087fd2e, which would be rendered as a short SHA1 [a5c3785](https://github.com/jlord/sheetsee.js/commit/a5c3785ed8d6a35868bc169f07e40e889087fd2e).